# Power BI Stacked Column Chart - X Axis Labels vertical or 45 Degrees

Tags: charts, powerbi, dax

I have a stacked column chart and a request to show the x axis labels vertically or at a 45 degree angle. Is this possible in Power BI as I can't see a way of achieving this.

If it is not possible is there a custom visual that would create the desired outcome?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of a stacked column chart, consider using a stacked horizontal chart, where the label are aligned with the visuals by default and you don't have to turn your head to read them.